# Записать весь путь из словаря в лист

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

У меня есть словарь

```
tree = {
    'video': {
        '2018': {
            '5': {
                '15': {
                    '922775.html': True
                },
                '7': {
                    '921441.html': True
                }
            },
            '6': {
                '7': {
                    '926645.html': True
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно записать все пути в лист.

В этом примере должно вернуть:

```
[
    ['video','2018','5','15','922775.html'],
    ['video','2018','5','7','921441.html'],
    ['video','2018','6','7','926645.html'],
]
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: такое ощущение что это ссылка типо: `/video/2018/5/15/922775.html`. Т.е. структура этих данных одинаковая

Comment: Да. Структура одинаковая

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from collections import Mapping

def get_ways(dct):             
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, Mapping):
            for way in get_ways(v):
                yield [k] + way
        else:
            yield [k]

print(list(get_ways(tree)))
```

Comment: `if isinstance(v, Mapping):` -> `if isinstance(v, dict):` или `if hasattr(v, 'items'):`?

Comment: Мне ваш пример с рекурсивным генератором понравился :)

Comment: Все что могу сказать -- чётко!

Comment: Даже думать не надо -) +

Comment: зачем `Mapping`. если достаточно `dict`?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, там может быть не dict, а OrderedDict, например. Поэтому считаю что лучше уж проверять на `hasattr(v, 'items')`

Answer (score 4):

Решение в лоб:

```
items = []

for k1, v1 in tree.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        for k3, v3 in v2.items():
            for k4, v4 in v3.items():
                for k5 in v4:
                    items.append([k1, k2, k3, k4, k5])

print(items)
```

Результат:

```
[
    ['video', '2018', '5', '15', '922775.html'], 
    ['video', '2018', '5', '7', '921441.html'], 
    ['video', '2018', '6', '7', '926645.html']
]
```

Comment: Унылое решение. Что если будет 100 вложенностей? у вас будет `k100` и 100 циклов?

Comment: @And, структура одинаковая, автор вопрос это подтвердил. Смысл извращаться и делать рекурсивное решение нет. Ваш минус незаслуженный. PS. я не случайно написал что решение в лоб

Comment: Извратились наоборот вы.

Comment: А что если структура будет разной  и мне нужно найти потомков с заданной глубины?

Comment: @KatalMach, если структура будет разной, т.е. мы не знаем сколько будет вложенностей, то нужно будет делать рекурсивную функцию, которая дойдет до последнего вложения. В вашем случае, я думаю, количество вложений не изменится -- вложенности состоит из даты и название файла: `[корень, yyyy, mm, dd, file_name]`, если добавится новый, дата, то алгоритм отработает

Comment: @And, какое решение вы предлагаете?

Comment: Интересно, зачем выделять "в лоб" жирным?)

Comment: @insolor, для некоторых... критиков :D

Answer (score 1):

Не самый эстетичный вариант однако это работает

```
def path(dic, depth, array, output):
    depth += 1
    for name, value in dic.items():
        try:
            array[depth] = name
        except IndexError:
            array.append(name)

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            path(value, depth, array, output)
        else:
            output.append(array[:])

    return output

print(path(tree, -1, [], []))
```